# I am getting the Error installing demo content

Tags: wordpress

I have purchased the augury wordpress theme but upon downloading and trying to import demo content, I am receive the error "Failed to create tmp table _fwbk_wp_actionscheduler_actions. Unknown storage engine 'InnoDB'". Any one with an idea what might be the problem?

I have tried repeating the process by reinstalling the theme but I still get the same error